# Convert varchar string to datetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am having an issue converting below to a DateTime, I am only able to get the date portion of the string. My goal is to get both the date & time.

```
declare @col varchar(14) = '20220602235900';
select CONVERT(datetime, CAST(@col AS varchar(8)), 121) dtimecre
```

Comment: What do you expect to find in the first 8 characters (`CAST(@col AS varchar(8))`)?

Comment: It return the date portion but when I tried to get all 14 I get a conversion error. Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Since you are `121` as you style option, you got to format your input string `20220602235900` like this `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steps:

1. Read the [documentation for `CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and pick the closest format to use
2. Do some string manipulation to get the desired format
3. Convert.

```
DECLARE @col varchar(14) = '20220602235900';

SELECT
    CONVERT(date, SUBSTRING(@col,1,8), 121) [Date Component]
    , CONVERT(time, SUBSTRING(@col,9,2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@col,11,2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@col,13,2), 8) [Time Component]
    , CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(@col,1,4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@col,5,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@col,7,2) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(@col,9,2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@col,11,2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@col,13,2), 120) [DateTime Representation];
```

Returns:

| Date Component | Time Component | DateTime Representation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-02 | 23:59:00.0000000 | 2022-06-02 23:59:00.000 |

Answer (score 0):

And another variant with a smaller amount of `SUBSTRING`:

```sql
DECLARE @col varchar(14) = '20220602235900';

SELECT DateComponent = CAST(DatePartString AS DATE),
       TimeComponent = CAST(TimePartString AS TIME),
       DateAndTime   = CAST(DatePartString + ' ' + TimePartString AS DATETIME)
FROM (VALUES(@col)) AS O (DateColumn)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT DatePartString = LEFT(DateColumn, 8),
           TimePartString = FORMAT(CAST(SUBSTRING(DateColumn, 9, 6) AS INT), '##:##:##')
) AS String;
```

Comment: Looks good, but `FORMAT` does have performance issues so should be avoided where possible.