# SQL date parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, casting

I am trying to convert bigint column to a date, and I then need to use this date as 2 parameters in SQL. I need to use a startdate off 20200101 and the end date needs to be today, like a getdate().

This is coming up with an error and I can't find out how to do it.

```
set @date1 TRY_CAST(CAST(CAST([DischargeDateKey] AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATETIME)
set @date2 TRY_CAST(CAST(CAST([DischargeDateKey] AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATETIME)

DECLARE @date1 AS datetime = 20200101
DECLARE @date2 AS datetime  = 20220531
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near 'TRY_CAST'.

Please someone please help?

Comment: You are trying to set a variable without an equal sign `SET @somevariable = <something>`. And then once you set them, you are declaring them and also setting them once again in the declaration? I don't follow your logic.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: I am using SSMS T-SQL. basically I am trying to use 2 parameters, one with a startdate of 20200101 and the end date of today which I think would be getdate(). the date column is a bigint and whenever I try to cast it as a date, i get an error.

Comment: Aside from the syntax error, dates are not INTs and shouldn't be stored as such.

Comment: You need to convert it to a format that is supported by convert - check the docs, you will probably need to add some additional characters to make it meet a supported format. Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72568059/convert-varchar-string-to-datetime/72568167#72568167)

Comment: I know, but the database I am accessing has them as INTs and I need to convert them

Comment: @DavidGoldstone did you see the answer I linked to above?